# Tower of tiles revisited

Tags: geometry

An S-tileset is a collection of n oriented tiles, where no two tiles have the same size, each tile is one unit thick, and its non-zero-integer length and width add up to n+1. (So, an S-tileset has n tiles, of sizes 1×n, 2×n−1, ...n×1.).

**Conjecture:** *No two disjoint subsets of any S-tileset can be tiled to form two areas of identical size and shape.*

Can you either prove the conjecture or find a counter-example.

Comment: Another conjecture: A subset (of an S-tileset) having more than one tile in it cannot tile a rectangle

Comment: I know this is a math puzzle, but the way it's written feels like it should go on Math.SE under the "puzzle" tag rather than actually here.

Comment: Do you allow rotation?  If so, the answer is trivial - simply use the 1xn tile normally, and the nx1 tile rotated 90 degrees.  They are disjoint, yet form two areas of identical size and shape.

Comment: @Trenin No, the tiles are oriented, so rotation is specifically disallowed.

Comment: @jwpat7 - a counterexample to your conjecture: http://imgur.com/k11J8zm. This is actually parametric in the n=14 set, there's a number of rectangles with the same layout. I suspect this might help find a counterexample to the posted conjecture.

Comment: @jwpat7 I don't think that is a counterexample. Using the n=14 tile-set You have tiled one 16x16 area using the subset of tiles 1x14, 3x12, 4x11, 8x7, 11x4, 12x3, and 13x2. For this to be a counterexample you would still need to produce another 16x16 area using the remaining unused tiles - i.e. 2x13, 5x10, 6x9, 7x8, 9x6, 10x5 and 14x1. As you have already used both the 3x12 and the 12x3, your second area can't be tiled in the same manner as the first.

Comment: @YenTheFirst, I agree that's a valid counterexample to my conjecture (in first comment above) that nondegenerate tile subsets cannot tile rectangles.

Comment: @Trenin, for more examples see [How high a tower of tiles can be made?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2053),

Comment: @YenTheFirst oops - sorry. I thought your counterexample was of the question's conjecture. The rectangle is a nice discovery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a counter-example to the conjecture, for N=860

(you may need to open the image in a new tab to read the sizes in the image)
[image: A counter-example]

The set of rectangles used:

Shape 1

- 602x259
- 210x651
- 28x833
- 133x728
- 469x392
- 679x182
- 707x154
- 840x21

Shape 2

- 196x665
- 70x791
- 161x700
- 413x448
- 609x252
- 770x91

Comment: That is an excellent result. Did you solve it using Diophantine equations?

Comment: Sort of. I set up systems of linear equations, and used sympy to solve or simplify them as much as possible. This ruled out a lot of candidates on its own (two sides would have the same algebraic length, for example). The system describing these two shapes ends up having only 1 free variable, so it's just a matter of picking the first one that gives integers for all sides.